# What cantilever brakes are compatible with Surly Pugsley 100mm front fork?

Tags: brakes, snow

I just purchased a Surly Pugsley project bike.  The front hub isn't set up for a disc brake so I'm looking to install a cantilever brake.  It has 65mm large marge rims.  I've scoured the internets and haven't found a recommendation for non disc brakes for the pugsley.

What cantilever brakes are compatible/recommended for use with Surly Pugsley 100mm front fork and the larger marge rim?

Comment: Does your fork have rim brake bosses?

Comment: I don't see any bosses in the picture on the site...  EDIT: I take that back.

Comment: @heltonbiker yes there are brake bosses on my fork.  The frame is a 2007 version.  I'm guessing the fork is a similar vintage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any medium-profile or low-profile cantilever brakes should work on the Pugsley; so long as you're using the Large Marge rims the effective cantilever post to rim spacing should be basically the same as a normal bike. The default spacing for most cantilever bosses is 80mm for use with a ~25mm wide rim.  On the Pugsley the bosses are spaced 120mm for a 65mm rim.

The Shimano "link wire" style straddle cables will almost certainly be too short,   For clearance, with whatever brake you use I'd plan on making it work with a high-quality yoke and a long straddle cable, as used on a wide-profile cantilever. You might even be most successful dialing in your own using a set of [cable knarps](http://sheldonbrown.com/harris/cable-hardware-brake.html#ends).

Comment: Thanks for the good info and good call on the cable knarps, I can see those in my future!